# Some Odd Word Order in The Comparison Structure As...As

Tags: grammar, word-order, comparative-constructions, as

As we know, in the structure **as...as** the first **as** modify the adjective or adverb that goes after it. We can also use a noun modified by an adjective in the structure; for example,

> They have as much *influence* as he has money.

However, I have seen the following examples in somewhere, whose word order is odd to me:

> He is as **good a cook** as his wife is.

And it has been stated there that the following sentence is not grammatically correct:

> *He is as **a good cook** as his wife is.

Regarding the first sentence example mentioned in this post, I wonder why the above sentence is not grammatically correct.

Comment: You already said the answer: *the first as modify the adjective or adverb that goes after it.*  "A good cook" is a noun phrase, not an adjective or adverb.

Comment: It's not correct because that is not how we say it in English!

Comment: @Later That is a good point.  I will have to think about that.  It may be as simple as "the *very next word* has to be an adjective or adverb, not a noun or determiner."